# Why is my application load balancer's health checks failing for iis website hosted on windows ec2 instance?

Tags: iis-8.5, aws-application-load-balancer

So we have a windows ec2 instance. It has iis installed on it. Now our php website in hosted on iis. And the index.php page is inside **C:/inetpub/wwwroot/project/public/index.php.**
But when I give this path in application load balancer health check path, it shows unhealthy instance with error message **"Health checks failed with these codes: 404"**
Cannot figure out what health check path to give to fix this?

The website is accessible via its domain name publicly.

Note : When I had the default iis website up, the load balancer health check was showing healthy instance, but after hosting my own website under default website in iis, I'm getting the health check failed error.

Comment: You need to provide a valid web URL, not a physical file path.

Comment: Application load balancer cannot check physical path, In particular, wwwroot only allows administrators to view it in windows. Load balancer is an external user to Windows.

Comment: So should I give a path like : domain_name.com/index.php?

Comment: Yes. You'd better give a http://domain/index.php url.